# Scroll bars for Excel CustomTaskPane developed using VSTO

Tags: vsto, excel-2013, customtaskpane

I have an add-in, developed using VSTO, that displays a custom task pane in Excel. This custom task pane holds a user control containing tree-view and other controls. I enabled AutoScroll for the user control and can see the traditional windows scroll bar when ever i re-size the control. However, i want the scroll bar to be similar to the scroll bars that exist in Thesaurus CTP in Excel 2013,when the CTP is in floating position and re-sized to smallest size, (i cant post images as i have reputation below 10). can any one provide pointers for this?

Also is there any way to restrict the minimum size of CustomTaskPane ?

Answer (score 0):

Hello Guruteja,

You can handle the Resize event of the Control class to control the size of your form and set the min size programmatically.

It looks like you need to develop a custom control to imitate the built-in one. Or try searching for any third-party Windows Forms controls.